# Como retirar mascara do campo antes de chamar o controller com asp net MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, .net

Em meu formulário de cadastro tenho um campo CNPJ com a mascara setada via jquery 
`$("#cnpj").mask("99.999.999/9999-99");` porém o valor esta chegando no meu controller formatado, em meu banco de dados este campo é float, existe uma forma de tratar isso sem ficar transformando o campo em string e realizar o replace?

Answer (score 1):

Opa, tudo bem?
Uma alternativa válida é você colocar o input referente á seu model como do tipo hidden:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Cnpj)
```

E então alterar o valor deste campo no momento do preenchimento da seu campo com mascara, vamos chamá-lo de cnpj-with-mask, ok?

Ficaria assim:

```
var options =  { 
  onChange: function(cnpj){
    $("#cnpj").val(cnpj);
  }
};

$('#cnpj-with-mask').mask('99.999.999/9999-99', options);
```

Answer (score 0):

A forma que encontrei pra resolver baseia-se em um campo `string` não-mapeado em *Model* e outro `decimal`, este sim mapeado:

```
    [Required]
    public Decimal Cnpj { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    [Cnpj] 
    public String CnpjMascara { get; set; }
```

Não recomendo usar `float` pra CNPJ porque `float` é uma estrutura que trabalha bem com números que tenham mantissa e característica, o que não é o caso do CNPJ.

O *Attribute* para validação do CNPJ está abaixo:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field, AllowMultiple = false)]
sealed public class CnpjAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (value == null) return null;

        int[] multiplicador1 = new int[12] { 5, 4, 3, 2, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2 };
        int[] multiplicador2 = new int[13] { 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2 };

        int soma, resto;

        string digito, tempCnpj, CNPJ;

        CNPJ = value.ToString().Trim();
        CNPJ = CNPJ.Replace(".", "").Replace("-", "").Replace("/", "");

        if (CNPJ.Length != 14)
            return new ValidationResult("CNPJ Inválido.");

        tempCnpj = CNPJ.Substring(0, 12);
        soma = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
            soma += int.Parse(tempCnpj[i].ToString()) * multiplicador1[i];
        resto = (soma % 11);

        if (resto < 2)
            resto = 0;
        else
            resto = 11 - resto;

        digito = resto.ToString();
        tempCnpj = tempCnpj + digito;
        soma = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++)
            soma += int.Parse(tempCnpj[i].ToString()) * multiplicador2[i];
        resto = (soma % 11);

        if (resto < 2)
            resto = 0;
        else
            resto = 11 - resto;

        digito = digito + resto.ToString();

        if (CNPJ.EndsWith(digito))
            return null;
        else
            return new ValidationResult("CNPJ Inválido.");
    }

    public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
    {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Como `CnpjMascara` já é validado pelo atributo, você só precisa fazer a atribuição para o tipo correspondente antes de passar pelo `ModelState`:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Empresa empresa)
    {
        if (empresa.CnpjMascara != null)
            empresa.Cnpj = Decimal.Parse(empresa.CnpjMascara.Replace(".", "").Replace("-", ""));

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
           /* Coloque aqui a lógica padrão */
        }
    }
```